# Are these designs too similar?

Tags: logo

I am starting up a brand and I gave my artist a few statue of liberty images from Pinterest for inspiration. The first image is the one he used for inspiration the most and the second image is the logo he came up with.

Are they too similar?

Inspiration -

[image]

Our Logo -

[image]

Comment: That logo ain't gonna scale well as is.

Comment: By scale do you mean in terms of resolution or scaling in regards to increasing or decreasing size for billboards etc?

Comment: Yep. Particularly down.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the second image has clearly been *purposefully* changed to be different than the original. The second image is NOT new or unique.....

Are they too similar? Well, only a judge could say for certain.

However, the changes do far, far, far more to make the new image appear *less professional, less clear, less powerful*.

Would I personally pay for that second image? Nope.

"Influence" is considerably different than "copy and mutilate to appear different".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a very immature logo concept. Not bad, immature. When drawing a logo, you have to get inspiration from many places, otherwise would be just a copy.

Copying is a good thing, but try to merge with other illustrations, take some part of this and increment with other concept you find congruent and develop better this logo.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: What do you mean by immature? I really want it to be near perfect so any advice helps :)

Comment: As an immature I mean it is a good logo, but it needs to be worked on more.

Comment: Ok thanks, my original question was unclear. Do you think once finished it would be too similar to the top drawing and possibly cause legal issues?